# Node js new Date() and Browser new Date() gives different dates

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found a problem about Dates. I'm actually using Mysql DB and Node JS, Browser is html. Dates comes from the Database, and a node is and the browser is all not the same when I write new Date () in Node it display 2021-07-31T22:46:30.312Z and when I write new Date in the browser's console I got Sat Jul 31 2021 23:47:25 GMT+0100. Please I need some explications

Comment: Node JS compile the date and show it in it's own format

Comment: Time zones. The node date has a `Z` aththe end which indicates `zulu` time, also known as `GMT`.  The browser has the local time with a `GMT` offset of `GMT+0100`. So your local time is one hour ahead of `GMT`.

Comment: what is the best idea of playing with dates between browser and server ,and the databases

Comment: I honestly don't know Node very well. But in theory all JavaScripts dates are an offset of the number if milliseconds since `Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`. If you type `New Date().GetTime()` in both environments, you should get a similar number

Comment: Or type `new Date().toISOString();`  in each environment, and you should get similar answers with the exception being the number of milliseconds that pass between entering it in one environment and the other.